# Consulta en el SQL

Tags: sql

Necesito que en mi SQL SERVER 2012, haga lo siguiente:
Que ejecute diariamente algunas cosas(órdenes de pacientes) que se van almacenando en la base de datos desde las 13hs hasta las 20hs.
Yo ya hice una consulta en donde me muestra esas cosas(órdenes de pacientes) desde las 7 hasta las 13hs.

Esto es lo que me da error:

```
SELECT A.PTA,A.ORD,A.OBS,A.FEC_ATE 

FROM TURNER.dbo.CLIORD A

WHERE A.FEC_ATE BETWEEN cast(convert(char(8), getdate(), 112) + ' 13:00:00.00' as datetime) AND  cast(convert(char(8), getdate(), 112) + ' 20:00:00.000' as datetime)
```

pero cuando lo ejecuto, me da error, me dice: `Error al convertir una cadena de caracteres en fecha y/u hora`

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español, mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funciona el sitio y de paso obtener tu primera medalla. Saludos.

Comment: Deberías detallar más la pregunta. ¿Quieres agregar un margen de horas en tu consulta o quieres que esa consulta se ejecute diariamente?

Comment: La pregunta es un poco pobre y no se entiende demasiado bien, deberías poner tu consulta y a partir de ahí nosotros intentamos darte una solución. Según entiendo, y si tu base de datos es mysql con poner en el WHERE `hour(fecha) between 13 and 20` debería bastar

Comment: no se para que base de datos.. pero uses la que uses, un cron job en la misma lo haria...

Comment: y como se ejecuta diariamente entre las 13 y las 20? una vez por hora? o que cosa? la consulta sigue siendo confusa...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día.

Prueba usar `CONVERT` en vez de `CAST` (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15); sería de:

```
cast(convert(char(8), getdate(), 112) + ' 13:00:00.00' as datetime)
```

a

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(10), getdate(), 23) + ' 13:00:00.00', 121)
```

usalo como corresponde para cada extremo en el `BETWEEN`.

Comment: Genio, Muchísimas gracias!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @OrnellaGreco tambien puedes intentar con `WHERE DATEPART(HH,A.FEC_ATE) BETWEEN 13 AND 20`

Comment: @OrnellaGreco si esta respuesta soluciono tu problema, recuerda aceptarla

Answer (score 0):

Tu base de datos es simplemente eso, un almacén de información. Si bien es cierto que se pueden automatizar ciertas cosas mediante procedures, triggers y schedules, que son eventos disparados por una acción previa, no vas a conseguir que después de ejecutar una consulta a una hora determinada, haga algo con ese resultado.

Tienes la mesa, que es la base de datos, pero necesitas un programa que son como las sillas para sentarte a comer. Ya bien sea PHP, un script en PowerShell, o una tarea programada de Windows o un cronjob de linux, que provoque la consulta y muestre el resultado de algún sitio, con algún formato, o algo de forma que la puedas manipular.

Comment: Claro que se puede hacer lo que dice, por ejemplo con un JOB, el tema es que la pregunta es confusa y necesita mas detalles. Saludos.

Comment: Yo no daría una solución como esa sin saber ni siquiera de qué estamos hablando. Habla SQL pero no se sabe si es SQL server o puramente SQL.

Comment: Exactamente, refuerza mi punto, ya que si no tenemos suficientes detalles cualquier respuesta es mera suposición.